# Multimode function shows only one result

Tags: python, usage-statistics

```
from numpy import genfromtxt
Birds = genfromtxt('DataLot.csv', dtype=int, delimiter=',')
import statistics
from collections import Counter
columnaA = Birds[:,1]
print(Counter(columnaA).most_common(6))
print("The multimode of list is : ", statistics.multimode(columnaA))
print("The mode of list is : ", statistics.mode(columnaA))
```

This gives me this result:

```
[(9, 93), (10, 90), (8, 89), (13, 83), (11, 83), (5, 80)]
The multimode of list is :  [9]
The mode of list is :  9
```

Why can't I get a Multimode list? If you see only shows one result for Multimode.

Answer (score 1):

This is right. Multimode shows only one result, because there is only one result to show.

The code below:

```
import statistics
from collections import Counter
columnaA = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7,8,8,9,9]
print(Counter(columnaA).most_common(6))
print("The multimode of list is : ", statistics.multimode(columnaA))
print("The mode of list is      : ", statistics.mode(columnaA))
```

prints:

```
[(1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 3), (5, 2), (6, 2)]
The multimode of list is :  [1, 2, 3]
The mode of list is      :  1
```

And as you can see from the printout of Counter there are **three most frequent values**, so the multimode gives a list with three elements.

**In case of your data there are no other items occurring the same number of times as the most frequent one, so there is only one value in the list.**

```
      v-- there is only one item with count 93 and this is the [9]
[(9, 93), (10, 90), (8, 89), (13, 83), (11, 83), (5, 80)]
```

Comment: ok, that´s it, better use collectiosn to handle mode analisys

Comment: You need to accept the answer if it solved your problem. That's the way stackoverflow works ...

Comment: @user3177225 *"better use collectiosn to handle mode analisys"* - Looks like you don't really want to do mode analysis then. As shown, the `statistics` functions work correctly here, you just have some mistaken expectation.